# Lessons/meetings/events at a certain time/at certain times

Tags: word-usage

I am referring here to the lessons schedule and want to know if the person has preferences for a certain time slot or don't they mind having lessons at any time (very flexible).

Can I say "Do you want to have lessons at certain times?" (Note: there will be a number of lessons)

Comment: The elephant in the room is that this way of phrasing the question is poor to begin with. You have used a much better wording in your explanation. Just take that much better wording and make *that* what you ask them. It doesn't need to be a footnote. It can be the actual question.

Comment: I see..Is there a better way to phrase the question that would start with "Do you want to have lessons ..."

Comment: No, there is not, because any question that starts that way is asking if they want to have *lessons*. If you want to ask them for their preferred time, ask them for their preferred time. And not for whether they want to have lessons at all. They've already told you that they do.

Comment: Yes, they have told me that they want to have lessons - but at certain times (only from 10:00 to 12:00) or are they flexible and any time is good? There are two options only: specific times and any time. I assume and this is the desired scenario that a person wants a specific time. 

How do I ask about this option (certain times) in a natural way?

Comment: What do you think about "What is your preferred lesson time?" Is it correct and does it sound natural?

Comment: Or will it be better to say "Prefer a certain lesson time?"